# How to debug bugs and errors in MIPS?

Tags: mips, spim

I have the below SPIM codes and am trying to determine what I did wrong. I couldn't find why my output didn't work.

```
.globl main

.data
     prompt1: .asciiz "Please enter the first pool size: "
     prompt2: .asciiz "Please enter the number to be selected from 1st pool: "
     prompt3: .asciiz "Please enter the second pool size: "
     prompt4: .asciiz "Please enter the number to be selected from 2nd pool: " 

     message: .asciiz "The odds are 1 in "

.text
     main: 
     #print 1st prompt and get its value
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0,prompt1
     syscall

     li $v0, 5
     syscall 

     move $t1, $v0 

     #print 2nd prompt and get its value
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0,prompt2
     syscall

     li $v0, 5
     syscall 

     move $t2, $v0 

     #print 3rd prompt and get its value
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0,prompt3
     syscall

     li $v0, 5
     syscall 

     move $t3, $v0 

     #print 2nd prompt and get its value
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0,prompt4
     syscall

     li $v0, 5
     syscall 

     move $t4, $v0 

     #perform the calculations for 1st poor
     move $t5,$t1
     addi $s0,$zero,1

     bge $t1,$t2,calc1  #if $t1 is greater than $t2, the loop continues
     sub $t6,$t5,$t2
     addi $s1,$zero,1
     bge $t6,$1,calc2 #if $t6 is greater than $zero, then the loop continues

     #perform the calculations for 2nd poor
     move $t7,$t3
     addi $s2,$zero,1

     bge $t3,$t4,calc3  #if $t1 is greater than $t2, the loop continues
     sub $t0,$t7,$t4
     addi $s3,$zero,1
     bge $t0,$1,calc4 #if $t6 is greater than $zero, then the loop continues

          #perform final calculation 
     div $s4, $s0,$s1
     div $s5, $s2,$s3

     mul $s6,$s4,$s5

     #display outputs
     li $v0,4
     la $a0,message
     syscall 

     li $v0,1
     move $a0,$s6
     syscall

     li $v0,10
     syscall

     #end of program
     calc1: 
           mul $s0,$s0,$t1
           addi $t1,$t1,-1
     calc2: 
           mul $s1,$s1,$t6
           addi $t6,$t6,-1
     calc3: 
           mul $s2,$s2,$t3 
           addi $t3,$t3,-1        
     calc4: 
           mul $s3,$s3,$t0
           addi $t0,$t0,-1
```

Comment: It would help [you] if you could repost the code so it's _all_ in a code block as it's difficult to read at present. Also, what is the program supposed to do and what/where do you _think_ the error is?

Comment: Use the debugging features in the simulator to step through your code until you find where it starts deviating from what you expected.

Comment: You branch to `calc1`, `calc2` etc, but then execution just runs off the bottom of the program. Did you mean to use call and return for each of them?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I appreciate all your help. This program is to calculate the odds to win a lottery. For example, one pool is to pick 5 numbers out of 50, and the other pool is to pick 2 numbers out out 11. We are calculating the odds (1 in ***) in this program. I was able to debug successfully as I realized my loops were not recursive, and as a result, the program didn't output anything.